# Supervisors are pushing me to keep trying with a bad paper- what can I do?

Tags: publications, phd, supervision

I wrote a paper towards the start of my PhD. It had nowhere near enough data- and by nowhere near I mean by an amount that it is not remotely publishable and would be laughable. It was rejected a couple of times, and I was tasked with changing it to hopefully get in somewhere, but I put it on the back burner. My PhD supervisors recently arranged a meeting with me to ask about it and I explained that even with the marginally more data they have, i don't think it would get in. Both of them were like "oh it'll be great, I think etc, get it done by x deadline" it will take me a lot of work to add this data (much of it mindless work that wouldn't benefit my skills) and I can't even begin to describe how depressed I am that I am being asked to do this when I am towards the end of my PhD. I think it's easy + risk free for them to ask this, but it isn't for me. I almost think I should quit and find a job. What should I do? Could I refuse? Should I just do it to not aggravate?

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to give good advice without knowing personalities. It is usually a bad idea to fight with supervisors, but perhaps you can negotiate a middle ground.

Maybe you can agree to spend the majority of your time and effort on your dissertation research, but promise that you will spend "some" time, perhaps negotiated, on the other project. A flat refusal, however, is probably less than optimal.

If you make "some progress" they might be satisfied (but - personalities...). Once you finish the degree you can judge for yourself whether to continue on the old project.

There might actually be a benefit in having a second, but secondary, project so that when you get stalled on the main work you have something to think about. Take some notes on the secondary work so that you can show it if asked.

The deadline set is more worrisome, however. If they are very vindictive then it could be a problem, but the usual case would be some disappointment but not a block. Good luck.